# Maven installation settings not showing in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-2

I have just installed Jenkins 2.6 (as a fresh install) but I can't seem to find the Maven installation options. Previously I would just be able to go to Jenkins configuration and in the Maven section there would be an option for `MAVEN_HOME` and to install Maven automatically. However this doesn't appear to be present for me.

I have the Maven integration plugin installed. How can I get these to show?

Comment: Since 2.0 theres also a dedicated tools configuration menu, maybe its there?

Comment: It would be nice if you accepted the answer. It is sort of how SO works...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Since Jenkins 2.x you can find all the tool configurations (Maven, Ant, Gradle and even the JDK) under the "Global Tools" entry in Jenkins administration (Manage Jenkins).

Comment: Excellent sir! Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey I have defined the MAVEN_HOME path under ADD maven and saved it later if see again the changes are not saved.Do you have any idea like what could be the exact reason.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but wanted to add a related information. If you are setting up Jenkins, then you will have to go to Jenkins plugins section and download/install the maven plugin.