# JDK path option is not showing while setting jenkins configuration

Tags: jenkins

I am setup Jenkins configuration, but put jdk path option is not showing in configure setting, i have also installed plugin but still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you trying to find out where you can specify a JDK in Jenkins?

If so, the JDKs are managed and specified under "Manage Jenkins" -> "Global Tool Configuration" -> "JDK installations".

If this is not what you're looking for, can you elaborate on your question a little bit more?  For example, what plugin you are referring to and what configure screen are you looking at?

Answer (score 1):

Since Jenkins 2.x you can find all the tool configurations (Maven, Ant, Gradle and even the JDK) under the "Global Tools" entry in Jenkins administration (Manage Jenkins).

check this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37431275/3583680

Answer (score 0):

**Jenkins version: 2.375.1**

1. You need to configure another [dummy JDK under Global Tool Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnpRU.png) as following: JDKDisplayBug
2. After that, you can see the [list of your JDKs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXSuZ.png) under project configuration.