# In Jenkins mvn is not recognized and the maven options are missing in config system

Tags: maven, jenkins, build

I started using Jenkins 2.73.1 on Windows 7.
I also have Apache Maven 3.5.0 installed.

My project build gives me the error " 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command".

After searching online, under Manage Jenkins and Sytem Configuration, there is a Maven Installation section that could be filled, however, I do not see this part when I go to the Configuration System page.

Why is this part missing & how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you typing `'mvn'` and not `mvn`? What is the command you're trying to execute?

Comment: Make sure the path where you installed Maven 's bin folder is in your environment variable PATH if not already.

Comment: Do you have [jenkins maven plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin) installed?

Comment: Please [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37391778/maven-installation-settings-not-showing-in-jenkins) to configure the maven.

Comment: i used mvn, path is defined for bin location, i believe plugin is installed by default recommended install....i found it Rishikesh..the page was moved to global tools section. thanks all.